# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'invoices' already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi i am trying to make an invoice app in Laravel and i got stuck, I am trying to run php artisan migrate but I get an error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `invoices` add constraint `invoices_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`id`))

  at C:\laragon\www\zorland-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\laragon\www\zorland-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   C:\laragon\www\zorland-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I tried to run php artisan migrate:refresh fresh, rollback but with no sucess.
I use HeidiSQL and when i run php artisan make:model InvoicesItem -m i could not create the table so i tried to create it in SQL database. Then i dropped the SQL database and tried again and i got this error.

InvoiceItem.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class InvoicesItem extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['invoice_id', 'name', 'quantity', 'price'];
}
```

InvoicesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Customer;
use App\Invoice;
use App\InvoicesItem;


class InvoicesController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function create() 
    {
        return view('invoices.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        $customer = Customer::create($request->customer);
        $invoice = Invoice::create($request->invoice + ['customer_id' => $customer->id]);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($request->product); $i++) {
            if (isset($request->qty[$i]) && isset($request->price[$i])) {
                InvoicesItem::create([
                    'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
                    'name' => $request->product[$i],
                    'quantity' => $request->qty[$i],
                    'price' => $request->price[$i]
                ]);
            }

        } 
        return 'To be continued';
    }
}
```

Migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateInvoicesItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('invoices_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
            $table->string('field_key');
            $table->string('field_value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('invoices_items');
    }
}
```

customers table migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('postcode')->nullable();
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have created invoices table in sql then why are you running migrate command ?

Comment: It is empty, i have droped it in HeidiSQL and tried to migrate it again but i get another error General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please update the question

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Do you have `customers` table? If then give the migration file of  `customers` table

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2):

In `CreateInvoicesItemsTable` migration file, you are using the wrong data type for `customer_id`. The data type for `customer_id` column will be `unsignedBigInteger`

Replace

```
$table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
```

With

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
```

Comment: This was it bdtiger but i had to replace it on CreateInvoicesTable and not on the reateInvoicesItemsTable migration file. Thanks anyway.